# Word list scrapper Merger and parse for duplicate entries trying too optimize and convert to python

Tags: python, bash, linux, shell, powershell

```
#!/bin/bash
reset

echo "Creating output folder to Desktop/CombinedText and final passwordlist will show up as Final0Duplicates.txt"

##Functions##


##output file detection and creation##


function Dependency_Check
{
    file2='~/Desktop/backupwordlist'
    if [ ! -f "$file2" ]
        touch "$file2"
    file2='~/Desktop/CombinedText'
    if [ ! -f "$file3" ]
        touch "$file3"
}
## sort and merge .txt files and list files##

function Combined_Sort 
{
##checks if file1 is not in directory##
 file1='Final.list'
 if [ ! -f "$file1" ]
    then
        echo "$file1 is not present"
        echo -e "\e[41m\e[5m[+]-------------------creating $file1 and adding all .txt files to it-----------[+]\e[0m"
        cat *.txt > Final.txt
        reset
        ##text_Troll
        sleep 2s
        echo -e "\e[42m\e[5m[+]-------------------Working on Final List-------------------------------------[+]\e[0m"
        cat Final.txt > Final.list
        reset
        echo -e "\e[42m\e[5m[+]--------final list finished removing 1.list-------[+]\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[41m\e[5mremoving Duplicates from Final list\e[0m"
        sleep 10s
        reset
        sort -u Final.list > Final0Duplicates.txt
        find . -name Final0Duplicates.txt -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/backupwordlist \;
        sleep 10s
 else
        echo "$file1 is present"
        echo "combining list files to 2.txt"
        cat *.list > 2.txt
        sleep 30s
        reset
        sleep 20s
        echo "Working on Final List"
        cat *.txt > Final.list
        echo "final list finished removing 1.list"
        echo "removing Duplicates from Final list"
        sort -u Final.list > Final0Duplicates.txt
        find . -name Final0Duplicates.txt -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/backupwordlist \;
        sleep 10s

 fi
}

##Crawls all subdirectories and extracts txt documents to desktop folder##


function crawl
{

    find . -name \*.txt -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/CombinedText \;
}


reset
crawl
reset
echo "crawling"
Dependency_Check
echo "Creating Dependency Folder on desktop "
Combined_Sort
echo "All Text Documents have been Combined and sorted."
sleep 6
```

> Okay so a break down of this project started as a pseudo code project out of boredom. but I was looking to see how this can be preformed in python. There are several functions in this code as a break down.

**Functions**

> **Dependency_Check**
> checks to see if the output folders are on the Desktop if not it creates it to be honest this is probably an unnecessary function
>
> **Combined_Sort**
> This takes all of the text documents and merges them into one text document than removes duplicate entries and outputs a file `Final0Duplicates.txt` to `~/Desktop/backupwordlist`
>
> **Crawler**
> This function crawls all subdirectories of the working folder and grabs all files with .txt extension copies them to `~/Desktop/CombinedText`
>
> **GOAL**
>
> *My Goal with this program is to possibly create this as a powershell script to work with windows or a batch file using system variables instead of importing a ton of libraries with python. any help would be greatly appriciated, Later this will be released on github as a tool for pentesters to build a master dictionary attack file. Feel free to use this code it is fully fuctional as of 4/9/2019 on 64 bit kali linux latest build and patch.*

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Here we review working code and try to make it better. This is not the right place to ask for help in rewriting your code in another language. Have a look at our [help/on-topic] for more information on what is on-topic here.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a lot of pointless `sleep`ing, running of needlessly expensive commands (`cat Final.txt > Final.list` instead of `cp Final.txt Final.list`) and weird comments (`##text_Troll`). Is this code meant as a joke?

Comment: so you're telling me you reimplemented  `cat ./**/*.txt | sort | uniq >> CombinedText` badly?

Comment: The Text troll was a joke that brought up a command window and told a sory about harambe the Guerrilla

Comment: Vogel612 Your a wizard and apparently I could have done this with that magic one liner of yours.....face palm with a pan

Comment: @Vogel612: `cat ./**/*.txt | sort -u >> CombinedText` would be [even faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76050/162318).